# UITextField inside UIScrollView - I want to detect tap when it's focused

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextfield

As topic's title says I want to do something when user touches UITextField and do something else when he will do it again. I noticed that there's no UITextFieldDelegate method that is giving this kind of information. Anyone could help me with that?

To make it sure - I don't want to recognize double tap on UITextField but getting notification always when user touched UITextField to do something on second click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own special logic in UITextField it would be easier to use custom class implementing UIKeyInput protocol (see:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput)